# Weblogic 12c (12.1.3) and eclipselink 2.3.1 Getting a ClassCastException for Named Native Queries

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, weblogic12c

Recently we migrated from weblogic 10 to weblogic12c. The application was working fine until we migrated to the new weblogic12c server. My web application is using JPA and eclipselink to fetch some information from the database. All other named query seems to be working fine, expect the Native Named query. I'm getting a classcastException. Below is the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my Named Native Query

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name="Channel.findValue",
            query="SELECT ID, APP_ID , APPLICATION_TYPE_ID, CHANNEL_ID, VALUE, EFFECTIVE_DATE FROM TABLENAME "+ 
            "  WHERE APP_ID = ? AND STATUS= ? AND APPLICATION_TYPE_ID = ?  AND CHANNEL_ID = ? AND EXPIRY_DATE >= ? AND EFFECTIVE_DATE <= ?  " 
,resultSetMapping="findFeeByAppTypeAndChannel")
})
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name="findValue",
          entities={@EntityResult(entityClass=Channel.class)}
    )
})
```

Code that's calling that's calling query:

```
List<Channel> channels =  em.createNamedQuery("channel.findVale").setParameter(1, app.getId())
.setParameter(2, ConstStatus.ACTIVE)
.setParameter(3, appType.getId())
.setParameter(4, channelId)
.setParameter(5, effectiveDate)
.setParameter(6, effectiveDate).setHint("eclipselink.refresh", "true").getResultList();
```

Error that I am getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ResultSetMappingQuery cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery
```

Full Stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Value Service Response:EJB Exception: : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ResultSetMappingQuery cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1987)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.refreshObjectIfRequired(ObjectBuilder.java:3591)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.EntityResult.getValueFromRecord(EntityResult.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ResultSetMappingQuery.buildObjectsFromRecords(ResultSetMappingQuery.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ResultSetMappingQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ResultSetMappingQuery.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:742)
    at weblogic.persistence.QueryProxyImpl.getResultList(QueryProxyImpl.java:140)
    at com.database.service.app.app.service.appServiceBean.getFeeByAppTypeAndChannel(appServiceBean.java:413)
    at com.database.service.app.app.service.appServiceBean_7omfhq_appServiceLocalImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:33)
    at com.database.service.app.app.service.appServiceBean_7omfhq_appServiceLocalImpl.getFeeByAppTypeAndChannel(Unknown Source)
    at com.database.service.app.ws.service.FeeService.getFeeInfo(FeeService.java:89)
    at com.database.service.app.ws.service.FeeService.getFee(FeeService.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:117)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:199)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:640)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:108)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:284)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:293)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:128)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)> 
<31-Mar-2016 11:26:58 o'clock AM ADT> <Error> <com.database.service.app.ws.service.FeeService> <BEA-000000> <Value Service Response:EJB Exception: : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ResultSetMappingQuery cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2073)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1987)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.refreshObjectIfRequired(ObjectBuilder.java:3591)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.EntityResult.getValueFromRecord(EntityResult.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ResultSetMappingQuery.buildObjectsFromRecords(ResultSetMappingQuery.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ResultSetMappingQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ResultSetMappingQuery.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2871)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1463)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getResultList(EJBQueryImpl.java:742)
    at weblogic.persistence.QueryProxyImpl.getResultList(QueryProxyImpl.java:140)
    at com.database.service.app.app.service.appServiceBean.getFeeByAppTypeAndChannel(appServiceBean.java:413)
    at com.database.service.app.app.service.appServiceBean_7omfhq_appServiceLocalImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:33)
    at com.database.service.app.app.service.appServiceBean_7omfhq_appServiceLocalImpl.getFeeByAppTypeAndChannel(Unknown Source)
    at com.database.service.app.ws.service.FeeService.getFeeInfo(FeeService.java:89)
    at com.database.service.app.ws.service.FeeService.getFee(FeeService.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:117)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:199)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:640)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:108)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:284)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:293)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:128)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

Comment: You didn't show the stack trace so its hard to say exactly what bug, but I believe it is something fixed in versions later versions, such as 2.5

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I did try changing the version to eclipselink2.5.2.jar, but got the same error :( Updated the question with full stack trace. Let me know if you need anything else. thanks again :)

Comment: I was able to get a successful result when I removed the "setHint("eclipselink.refresh", "true")" from


`List<Channel> channels =  em.createNamedQuery("channel.findVale").setParameter(1, app.getId())
.setParameter(2, ConstStatus.ACTIVE)
.setParameter(3, appType.getId())
.setParameter(4, channelId)
.setParameter(5, effectiveDate)
.setParameter(6, effectiveDate). setHint("eclipselink.refresh", "true").getResultList();`

Comment: However, I'm wondering if removing eclipselink.refresh may cause other issues.

Comment: I'd file a bug as the refresh hint and your reference mapping settings are forcing it to go into a codepath that expects the native query to be an ObjectLevelReadQuery.  Are you using an eager relationship?  You might try a fetch join and add it to your return values, or make the relationship lazy to be fetched later.

Comment: Sure will log a bug for this. By the way, I'm using a lazy weaving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error got resolved when I removed the 
`setHint("eclipselink.refresh", "true")`

from

```
List<Channel> channels = em.createNamedQuery("channel.findVale")
.setParameter(1, app.getId()) 
.setParameter(2, ConstStatus.ACTIVE) 
.setParameter(3, appType.getId())
.setParameter(4, channelId) .setParameter(5, effectiveDate)
.setParameter(6, effectiveDate)
.setHint("eclipselink.refresh", "true").getResultList();
```